# NullReferenceException when dragging control onto Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

This problem started occurring yesterday: I am trying to drag a button onto a form in a Windows Forms application, but when I do this I get a `NullReferenceException` (see screenshot  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqRl9.png))
When I don't use drag & drop, it works fine.

I'm using Windows 10 1803 together with Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 (version 15.9.14)

Any ideas on what may have caused this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it has nothing to do with Visual Studio or Windows. My second monitor is attached to my laptop with a VGA cable, and it turns out, when I upscale the monitor, the designer in Visual Studio acts weird.

I noticed it because dragging controls worked when visual studio was displayed on my laptop screen, but not on my VGA monitor.

Turning the scale back to 100% (right mouse click on desktop > display settings) solved the issue for me.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting Visual Studio AppData folder? It is usually at %LOCALAPPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio.

You can also try out Visual Studio Community edition 2019. Maybe in new version this problem won't occur.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this did not work for us.

Comment: The problem also occurs in Visual Studio Community Edition 2019